# Best way to populate large file list in c# DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a program which fills a DGV with file details such as name, date etc, and also a few extra custom columns that give info about the files.  This works fine until there is a huge amount of files in which case the DGV seems to get slower as it populates.

From reading about DGV, it seems the best way to fill these with large amounts of data is to bind the contents to a database source.

So, the question is, would the most effective way for me to do this be to parse the files (and fill in my own custom data) then write these to a temp database, then use this to fill the DGV?  Or am I making heavy work of something much simpler?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: is this windows-forms or wpf?

Comment: @Tigran The DataGridVIEW exists only in WinForms. It's just DataGrid in other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the responsiveness of a DGV by using VirutalMode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge amount of rows, like 10 000 and more,

to avoid performance leak - do the following before data binding:

dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing; //or even better .DisableResizing. Most time consumption enum is DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders

dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false; // set it to false if not needed

after data binding you may enable it.